# Aplicar estilo a estado Activo o Inactivo con php en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

sucede que tengo mi plantilla **index.blade.php**  en el cual cargo el listado de artículos, me gustaría que el estado **Inactivo** aparezca de color rojo, no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo soy novato en laravel y php, de echo me incline por este framework para evitar hacer tanto código php gracias a las plantillas blade..

supongo que debo implementar un if algo así como

```
if (estado.equals("Inactivo")){}
```

pero no tengo la mas minima idea espero me puedan ayudar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el archivo **index.balde.php**

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('contenido')
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <h3>Listado de articulos <a href="almacen/articulo/create"><button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-success">nuevo</button></a></h3>
    @include('almacen.articulo.serch')
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Codigo</th>
          <th>Categoria</th>
          <th>Stock</th>
          <th>Imagen</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          <th>Opciónes</th>
        </thead>
        @foreach($articulos as $art)
        <tr>
          <td>{{$art->idarticulo}}</td>
          <td>{{$art->nombre}}</td>
          <td>{{$art->codigo}}</td>
          <td>{{$art->categoria}}</td>
          <td>{{$art->stock}}</td>
          <td>
            <img src="{{asset('/imagenes/articulos/'.$art->imagen)}}" alt="{{$art->nombre}}" width="100px" height="100px" class="img-thumbnail" />
          </td>
          <td>{{$art->estado}}</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" name="button">Editar</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </table>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>


@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigos gracias por comentar teniendo en cuenta sus códigos resolví mi inquietud de la siguiente manera.

```
   @foreach($articulos as $art)
        <tr>
          <td>{{$art->idarticulo}}</td>
          <td>{{$art->nombre}}</td>
          <td>{{$art->codigo}}</td>
          <td>{{$art->categoria}}</td>
          <td>{{$art->stock}}</td>
          <td>
            <img src="{{asset('/imagenes/articulos/'.$art->imagen)}}" alt="{{$art->nombre}}" width="100px" height="100px" class="img-thumbnail" />
          </td>
          <td>
            @if($art->estado == 'Inactivo')
            <span class="text-danger">{{$art->estado}}</span>
            @else
            <span class="text-success">{{$art->estado}}</span>
            @endif
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" name="button">Editar</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

De esta manera obtengo **Inactivo** en color rojo y **Activo** en color verde, un abrazo.

Answer (score 2):

Tomando en cuenta la respuesta anterior seria algo diferente ya que tendrías que poner de color toda la linea, yo haría algo mas o menos así:

```html
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('contenido')
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <h3>Listado de articulos <a href="almacen/articulo/create"><button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-success">nuevo</button></a></h3>
    @include('almacen.articulo.serch')
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Codigo</th>
          <th>Categoria</th>
          <th>Stock</th>
          <th>Imagen</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          <th>Opciónes</th>
        </thead>
        @foreach($articulos as $art)
        //Utilizaria los estilos de bootstrap que ya nos da por defecto
        <tr class="@if($art->estado == 'Inactivo') table-danger @endif">
          <td>{{$art->idarticulo}}</td>
          <td>{{$art->nombre}}</td>
          <td>{{$art->codigo}}</td>
          <td>{{$art->categoria}}</td>
          <td>{{$art->stock}}</td>
          <td>
            <img src="{{asset('/imagenes/articulos/'.$art->imagen)}}" alt="{{$art->nombre}}" width="100px" height="100px" class="img-thumbnail" />
          </td>
          <td>{{$art->estado}}</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" name="button">Editar</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </table>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Con la clase `table-danger` de bootstrap empleara el color rojo que necesitas sin necesidad crear un css.

Comment: La pregunta dice: "que el estado inactivo aparezca de color rojo", no dice que la línea completa sea de color rojo.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es utilizar blade, tan solo debes usar su condicional `@if ... @endif` para agregar una clase al contenedor del texto "Inactivo" y cambias el color en tu archivo css.

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('contenido')
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <h3>Listado de articulos <a href="almacen/articulo/create"><button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-success">nuevo</button></a></h3>
    @include('almacen.articulo.serch')
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Codigo</th>
          <th>Categoria</th>
          <th>Stock</th>
          <th>Imagen</th>
          <th>Estado</th>
          <th>Opciónes</th>
        </thead>
        @foreach($articulos as $art)
        <tr>
          <td>{{$art->idarticulo}}</td>
          <td>{{$art->nombre}}</td>
          <td>{{$art->codigo}}</td>
          <td>{{$art->categoria}}</td>
          <td>{{$art->stock}}</td>
          <td>
            <img src="{{asset('/imagenes/articulos/'.$art->imagen)}}" alt="{{$art->nombre}}" width="100px" height="100px" class="img-thumbnail" />
          </td>
          <td class="@if($art->estado == 'Inactivo') inactivo @endif">{{$art->estado}}</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" name="button">Editar</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </table>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

y en tu archivo de css sería algo así

```
td.inactivo {
  color: red;
}
```